# Append list elements to data frame column

Tags: r

I have this dataframe:

```
       GO.ID Annotated Significant Expected P-value                   Term Ontology
1 GO:0000049         7           0     0.25  1.0000           tRNA binding       MF
2 GO:0000062         4           0     0.14  1.0000 fatty-acyl-CoA binding       MF
```

And I have this list:

```
$`GO:0000049`
[1] "Solyc02g090860.2" "Solyc03g119280.2" "Solyc05g056260.2" "Solyc06g048610.2" "Solyc07g008950.2" "Solyc08g015960.2"
[7] "Solyc10g007060.2"

$`GO:0000062`
[1] "Solyc01g099350.2" "Solyc03g082910.2" "Solyc04g078090.2" "Solyc08g075690.2"
```

Is there any way to print the elements of the list to a new column of the data frame? The order is the same in both structures, I mean, the GO.ID column is ordered as the list elements. I'm looking for something like paste bash command.

I've tried `lapply` and export the list to a file. Then `write.table` with the dataframe and then `paste` command in bash. But I'm wondering if there is a way to do this kind of job in R.

And yes, I'm newbie to R world.

**EDIT:**

This is my desired output:

```
       GO.ID Annotated Significant Expected P-value                   Term Ontology           Gene_ID
1 GO:0000049         7           0     0.25  1.0000           tRNA binding       MF           Solyc02g090860.2,Solyc03g119280.2,Solyc05g056260.2,Solyc06g048610.2,Solyc07g008950.2,Solyc08g015960.2,Solyc10g007060.2
2 GO:0000062         4           0     0.14  1.0000 fatty-acyl-CoA binding       MF           Solyc01g099350.2,Solyc03g082910.2,Solyc04g078090.2,Solyc08g075690.2
```

Comment: What do you mean "print to a new column"? Do you want convert the list("Solyc...") to a string and add it as a new column, or do you want to have seven rows with `GO.ID = GO:0000049` and four rows with `GO.ID = GO:0000062` with respective values from the lists?

Comment: Sorry, I've not specified correctly. See the edit please. Hope it clarifies a bit. PD: The list can be separated by space, not necessarily by comma.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `df` is your data.frame and `lst` your list, you can do:

```
transform(df, Gene_ID=sapply(lst, paste0, collapse=',')[GO.ID])
```

Comment: This solution is simple, easy to understand and it works perfect. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry but is there any way to transform the list to dataframe in the same way as you did, but, without comparing with the dataframe? Just create a dataframe from the list.

Comment: something like `df1 = data.frame(col=sapply(lst, paste0, collapse=','),GO.ID=names(lst))`

Answer (score 2):

(I apologise for using `dplyr` here. All of this can be done using built-in R functions but I don't remember the last time I used them)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# sample data
l <- list("GO.0000049" = c(1,2,3), "GO:0000062" = c(4,5,6))
df <- data.frame(GO.ID = c("GO.0000049", "GO:0000062"), Annotated = c(7,4), stringsAsFactors = F)

# actual magic
result <- gather(as_data_frame(lapply(l, function(x) paste(x, collapse=","))), "GO.ID", "Gene_ID") %>% inner_join(df)
```

And your `result` would be:

```
Source: local data frame [2 x 3]

       GO.ID Gene_ID Annotated
1 GO.0000049   1,2,3         7
2 GO:0000062   4,5,6         4
```

Comment: Thanks Anton. When I run your code, I get the following error: Error: could not find function "%>%". Any idea?

Comment: you have to load `library(dplyr)` containing the pipe character (originally in magrittr package)